# How to tell a Mockito mock object to return something different the next time it is called?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

So, I'm creating a mock object as a static variable on the class level like so...  In one test, I want `Foo.someMethod()` to return a certain value, while in another test, I want it to return a different value.  The problem I'm having is that it seems I need to rebuild the mocks to get this to work correctly.  I'd like to avoid rebuilding the mocks, and just use the same objects in each test.

```
class TestClass {

    private static Foo mockFoo;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        mockFoo = mock(Foo.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        when(mockFoo.someMethod()).thenReturn(0);

        TestObject testObj = new TestObject(mockFoo);

        testObj.bar(); // calls mockFoo.someMethod(), receiving 0 as the value

    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        when(mockFoo.someMethod()).thenReturn(1);

        TestObject testObj = new TestObject(mockFoo);

        testObj.bar(); // calls mockFoo.someMethod(), STILL receiving 0 as the value, instead of expected 1.

    }

}
```

In the second test, I'm still receiving 0 as the value when testObj.bar() is called... What is the best way to resolve this?  Note that I know I could use a different mock of `Foo` in each test, however, I have to chain multiple requests off of `mockFoo`, meaning I'd have to do the chaining in each test.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First of all don't make the mock static. Make it a private field. Just put your setUp class in the `@Before` not `@BeforeClass`. It might be run a bunch, but it's cheap.

Secondly, the way you have it right now is the correct way to get a mock to return something different depending on the test.

Answer (score 560):

You could also [**Stub Consecutive Calls**](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#10) (#10 in 2.8.9 api). In this case, you would use multiple **thenReturn** calls or one **thenReturn** call with multiple parameters (varargs).

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestClass {

    private Foo mockFoo;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        setupFoo();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        TestObject testObj = new TestObject(mockFoo);

        assertEquals(0, testObj.bar());
        assertEquals(1, testObj.bar());
        assertEquals(-1, testObj.bar());
        assertEquals(-1, testObj.bar());
    }

    private void setupFoo() {
        mockFoo = mock(Foo.class);

        when(mockFoo.someMethod())
            .thenReturn(0)
            .thenReturn(1)
            .thenReturn(-1); //any subsequent call will return -1

        // Or a bit shorter with varargs:
        when(mockFoo.someMethod())
            .thenReturn(0, 1, -1); //any subsequent call will return -1
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can also take advantage of the fact that .thenReturn() takes varargs, so the code can be shortened to: when(mockFoo.someMethod()).thenReturn(0, 1, -1);

Comment: @JustinMuller - that's worth a separate answer, I think (as opposed to a comment)

Comment: This answer is not the correct thing to do in this case.  If you stub this method to return 0 and 1, then you'll be fine so long as you run `test1` and then `test2`.  But it may be that your continuous integration environment will run the tests in the other order.  Or it may be that you'll want to run `test2` by itself, without running `test1` first, in which case it will fail.  Unit tests _must_ always be independent of each other; and there should _never_ be a dependency between individual tests, or a dependency on a particular ordering of tests.  Whereas chaining `thenReturn` statements ...

Comment: ... has its uses, as does using varargs for a single `thenReturn`, it's not a correct solution in this particular case. It seems to me that the hordes of upvoters here have most likely failed to understand the question.

Comment: Junit itself does not ensure test order without `@FixMethodOrder`

Comment: @DavidWallace, as far as I know, the test class is instantiated for every test and methods marked `@Before` are run before every test, so I don't see a problem here with test order. Maybe the answer has been edited since your comment. Or do I get something wrong?

Comment: Didn't know you could string together returns like that, very nice thank you!

Comment: also if you use spy() you will need this: doReturn(obj1).doReturn(obj2).when(this.client).somemethod();

Answer (score 78):

For all who search to return something and then for another call throw exception:

```
when(mockFoo.someMethod())
        .thenReturn(obj1)
        .thenReturn(obj2)
        .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Fail"));
```

or

```
when(mockFoo.someMethod())
        .thenReturn(obj1, obj2)
        .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Fail"));
```

Answer (score 47):

Or, even cleaner:

```
when(mockFoo.someMethod()).thenReturn(obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: I ran into a situation where I wanted to test a mock returning something inside a while loop. This solves it since you can always use thenReturn(obj1, obj2, null) to get out of the loop.

Answer (score 30):

**For Anyone using spy()** and the doReturn() instead of the when() method:

what you need to return different object on different calls is this:

```
doReturn(obj1).doReturn(obj2).when(this.spyFoo).someMethod();
```

.

For classic mocks:

```
when(this.mockFoo.someMethod()).thenReturn(obj1, obj2);
```

or with an exception being thrown:

```
when(mockFoo.someMethod())
        .thenReturn(obj1)
        .thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException())
        .thenReturn(obj2, obj3);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't understood why it does not work with when but works with doReturn()