# Using Mockito for multiple calls to same method and different outputs

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I want to use mockito and stub a method. I want method to return different values basing on stubbing. But it always returns the first output. Below is how is my setup

```
Class Controller{    //this is singleton class

private final Foo foo=AFacftory.getFoo();    //this variable is initialized only once for the whole life cycle

//Some code below that I want to test is here
foo.functionInFoo()



}

    Class Foo{
    int functionInFoo(){

    }
}

Test1
Foo foo=Mockito.mock(Foo.class)
TestSettings.Provider.get().setTestBeanProvider(Foo.class, foo);
Mockito.when(foo.functionInFoo()).thenReturn(XXX);
hitAUrl();
//do some testing here using xxx.

Test2
Foo foo=Mockito.mock(Foo.class)
TestSettings.Provider.get().setTestBeanProvider(Foo.class, foo);
Mockito.when(foo.functionInFoo()).thenReturn(YYY);
hitAUrl();
//do some testing here using YYY.
```

The variable foo is instantiated only once for the whole life time as it is part of the controller.
So when I run my first test, the controller gets initialized when I hitAUrl() and it gets the mocked instance of Foo and returns XXX. But when I run the second test, it will still have the previous mock instance and return XXX again. I want it to return YYY. If I restart the server after Test1, it returns YYY. But this has to work without restarting. Please let me know how I can fix this. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This question is answered here (check the 2nd answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216569/how-to-tell-a-mockito-mock-object-to-return-something-different-the-next-time-it?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

`Mockito.when(foo.functionInFoo()).thenReturn(XXX, YYY);`

This will return `XXX` when `foo.functionUnFoo()` is called for the first time and `YYY` every time after that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that static factory methods can be mocked using Mockito.
But I always use PowerMockito [ PowerMock + Mockito ] to mock static methods & private methods.

```
Foo foo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(AFacftory.class);
PowerMockito.when(AFacftory.getFoo()).thenReturn(foo);
```