# Mockito/PowerMockito: mock final static member cannot return different values in different methods

Tags: mockito

There is a `final static` member in class `ToBeTestClass`:

```
protected final static LMSServiceHelper externalService;
```

I mock it with

```
@Mock
protected LMSServiceHelper externalService;
```

Then I want to get different values in different test methods:

```
public void testMethod1() {
    PowerMockito.when(externalService.getSomething).thenReturn("aaa");
}

public void testMethod2() {
    PowerMockito.when(externalService.getSomething).thenReturn("bbb");
}

public void testMethod3() {
    PowerMockito.when(externalService.getSomething).thenReturn("ccc");
}
```

However, I can't get "bbb" or "ccc" whereas always get "aaa". It seems when I set the return value first time, and it will never changes.

Anyone has met this?

Comment: Could you please give a **full**  [mcve]. And alone the idea of using a **static** field in in inheritance context (protected) ... sounds strange. I would rather look into changing production code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    Mockito.when(externalService.getSomething)
           .thenReturn("aaa")
           .thenReturn("ccc")
           .thenReturn("ccc"); //any subsequent call will return "ccc"
}
```

[How to tell a Mockito mock object to return something different the next time it is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216569/how-to-tell-a-mockito-mock-object-to-return-something-different-the-next-time-it)

Answer (score 0):

Reset your mocked object as shown below then you will see different values

```
public void testMethod1() {
PowerMockito.when(externalService.getSomething).thenReturn("aaa");
Mockito.reset(externalService);
```

}

```
public void testMethod2() {
    PowerMockito.when(externalService.getSomething).thenReturn("bbb");
    Mockito.reset(externalService);

}


public void testMethod3() {
    PowerMockito.when(externalService.getSomething).thenReturn("ccc");

    Mockito.reset(externalService);

}
```

Comment: I finally resolved the issue by using `when(someMock.someMethod()).doReturn("aaa").doReturn("bbb").doReturn("ccc"));`

Comment: Sorry. I tried the reset, but it doesn't work. They always return "aaa".