# RxJava Unit test Observable interval, Change response by advancing through time

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java

I have a network polling function with Observable interval in my repository

```
class repository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: api,
    private val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
) {

    private fun networkPoll(): Observable<response> {
        return Observable.interval(1L, TimeUnit.Seconds, schedulerProvider.io())
            .startWith(0L)
            .flatMap {
                api.getStatus().subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io()).toObservable()
            }
    }

    private fun pollStates(): Observable<State> {
        return networkPoll()
            .map {
                // map the response to State1, State2, State3
            }
    }

    fun pollForState3(): Observable<State> {
        return pollStates()
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
            .takeUntil {
                it is State3
            }
    }

}
```

How do I unit test pollForState3 and change the response by advancing through time?

Comment: Have `schedulerProvider.io()` return a `TestScheduler` and advance it manually.

Comment: @akarnokd thanks a lot! it worked partially. What I need now is to change the API response by advancing through the time and making sure the polling has stopped and the state has changed. I have updated the question

Comment: I'm not sure if remocking actually works, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4216569/61158

Comment: my bad! I made a mistake in my code. it works!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this

```
private lateinit var repository: Repository
private val schedulerProvider = TestSchedulerProvider()

@Mock
private lateinit var api: Api

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        repository = repository(api, schedulerProvider)
    }

@Test
fun test() {
    `when`(api.getStatus()).thenReturn(
        // return such a way that pollStates function map this to State1
    )
    val testObserver = repository.pollForState3().test()
    schedulerProvider.ioScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    testObserver.assertValue {
        it is State1
    }
    testObserver.assertNotTerminated()

    `when`(api.getStatus()).thenReturn(
        // now return such a way that pollStates function map this to State3
    )
    schedulerProvider.ioScheduler.advanceTimeBy(2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    testObserver.assertValue {
        it is State3
    }
    testObserver.assertTerminated()
    testObserver.dispose()
}
}
```